Почему не выводится значение стиля в JS?
Пытаюсь посмотреть значение margin-left через JS, но ничего не получается. В чем может быть проблема?
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const slides = document.querySelector('.sliders>.block');
    
    document.querySelectorAll('.sliders>.arrow').forEach(arrow => {
        arrow.addEventListener('click', () => {
            Array.from(slides.children).forEach(item => {
                console.log(item);
                console.log(item.style.marginLeft + ' px');
            });
        });
    });
});


вот результат:


Очевидно в style этих компонентов нет определения свойств marginLeft... Используй getComputedStyle для получения нужных данных. https://code.mu/ru/javascript/manual/dom/getComputedStyle/

Вы пытаетесь получить стиль через item.style, а он там будет только если задан через style. Например так: <div style="margin-left: 20px;">text</div>
Нужно использовать getComputedStyle, что бы получить все стили css класса
const element = document.querySelector('.bottom-share-links');
const computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(element);
const marginLeft = computedStyle.marginLeft;

console.log(marginLeft);

